# Flutter: use 2 classes when using StateMixin in getx controller

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using getx as a statemanagement on my project. I created a controller and I am using StateMixin on my controller.

```
class HomeController extends GetxController
    with StateMixin<MyModel, List<MyCompleteModel>> {
```

As you can see I want to use 2 classes by `StateMixin`. But it's constructor just accepts one class.
Except create a new class that contains both of these classes, Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! And as you guessed it, by inheritance.

At first create a generic State class containing the types you want:

```
class MyState<T1, T2> { // you can use more like T3, T4...
      T1? state1;
      T2? state2;

      MyState({this.state1, this.state2});
}
```

Then create a base controller of your own:

```
abstract class BaseController<T1, T2> extends GetxController with StateMixin<MyState<T1, T2>> {

}
```

Then extend this base controller:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController<int, String> {
      @override
      void onInit() {
         super.onInit();

         change(null, status: RxStatus.loading());

         Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
            change(MyState(state1:1,state2: "state2"), status:RxStatus.success());
    });
  }
}
```

Then on your widget:

```
controller.obx(
      (state) => Text("${state?.state1} - ${state?.state2}"),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using `tuple` package.
https://pub.dev/packages/tuple

```dart
class HomeController extends GetxController
    with StateMixin<Tuple2<MyModel, List<MyCompleteModel>>> {
  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    change(Tuple2(MyModel(), [MyCompleteModel()]), status: RxStatus.success());
  }
}
```

```dart
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(HomeController());
    return controller.obx((state) => Column(
      children: [
        Text(state?.item1.toString() ?? ''),
        Text(state?.item2.first.toString() ?? ''),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```